# Расположение элементов на layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Возникла необходимость расположить элементы очень своеобразным образом. А значит линейный и табличные размещения тут не помогут. Задумался об абсолюте. Но гугл пишет, что его использовать не желательно. Как выйти из положения с размещением элементов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абсолютная разметка устарела (deprecated), и использовать ее больше нет смысла. Главная причина, почему от нее отказались, - это проблемы при отображении на экранах с разными размерами.

Сейчас произвольное расположение элементов достигается с помощью FrameLayout (путем наложения и задания необходимых отступов), подробнее - [Layout Tricks: Merging Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).

Если расположение элементов реально очень сложное и сами элементы необычные, возможно, придется рисовать все самостоятельно с помощью [2D Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).

Comment: Вообщем сейчас главная проблема. Это в том что некоторые элементы могут быть друг на друге, вот требуеться реализовать оверлей.

Comment: По ссылке про FrameLayout показано, как это делать. Там в примере на картинку накладывается текст или кнопки.

Comment: Получается полный аналог свободного лейаута

Comment: Хорошо, в принципе пойдет. Спасибо.